# there's anyone know how to load webview flutter without header or footer?

Tags: flutter, webview

I want to show a particular website in a widget but without header and footer. is this possible in Flutter? i tried with webview flutter and can't find it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the website is developed by you, you should do the checking of user agent in backend, and response different versions of the web page respectively.

If the website is not developed by you, one of the approach I could think of is using `WebViewController.evaluateJavascript` method to inject some JavaScript to hide/remove the DOM from the webpage.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this package for simple my webviews [webview_package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappwebview)